# Does CNAME only work for subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Does `CNAME` only work for subdomains? I wonder because I want to redirect from the domain name I registered, say, `www.mycoolname.com`, to my page at one of the famous social network web sites, say, `www.fakebooked.net/coolnameofmine`. Does anybody know if that is possible to accomplish somehow changing some DNS settings?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:  no.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

You can use URL forwarding services to achieve what you want to do ... which are fancy implementations of an iFRAME.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. CNAME is just like an alias for a domain name (like `www.mycoolname.com` or `www.facebooked.net`). You cannot alias to another URL (like `http://www.facebooked.net/coolnameofmine`), because domains are not URLs.

In this example, the closest you can come is to have a CNAME from `www.mycoolname.com` to `www.facebooked.net`.

This would mean going to the URL `http://www.mycoolname.com/coolnameofmine` would probably be equivalent to `http://www.facebooked.net/coolnameofmine`

- (unless the server at `www.facebooked.net` only responds to `www.facebooked.net`)

Of course, it would also mean that goign to `http://www.mycoolname.com` would be the same as going to `http://www.facebooked.net/` which is not what you want.

---

The simplest thing you can do is check your domain registrar. Most of the big ones have options for how your domain works: they often let you chose from them hosting various DNS records, pointing your domain to external name servers, or setting up redirects. It's very likely you can just configure your domain using the control panel at your registrar to redirect.

The second best thing is to find a service that does URL forwarding (there are many), and then configure your domain appropriately (they'll have instructions on how to do it).

Comment: If I want to call tim.netlify.app from tim.com, is this possible with `cname`? My domain registrar at tim.com wants to do forwarding which is not what I want. I want my website to stay at tim.com.

Answer (score 0):

> Does CNAME only work for subdomains?

- CNAME can work for any domain and is not only for subdomains. It'll work from `mycoolname.com` -> `fakebooked.net`

> [www.fakebooked.net/coolnameofmine](http://www.fakebooked.net/coolnameofmine)

- This is a url, not a domain, CNAME won't be able to point you from `mycoolname.com` -> `fakebooked.net/coolnameofmine`. But if you set a CNAME for mentioned domains navigating to `mycoolname.com/coolnameofmine` to `fakebooked.net/coolnameofmine` will work.